# Encoding with url and api

Tags: python, encoding, flask

So I have this web app set up and running and it works fine for any username that you request, but when i try http://mrcastelo.pythonanywhere.com/lol/euw/Nazaré, it simply doesnt work - the error that I get on the server is the following:

```
iddata= getJSON(urllolbase+region+urlid+username) #SummonerID
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It is annoying me greatly, I've tried some other threads but none of them came to a fix. The api that I am using (www.legendaryapi.com) does accept this because [this](http://www.legendaryapi.com/api/v1.0/euw/summoner/getSummonerByName/Nazar%C3%A9) works.

Any idea on how to fix this?

```
urllolbase = 'http://www.legendaryapi.com/api/v1.0/'
urlid = '/summoner/getSummonerByName/'
urlps = '/summoner/getAllPublicSummonerDataByAccount/'

def getJSON(url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(response)
    return data
```

Comment: See that é in Nazaré. That's the cause of the error.

Comment: You'll need to show more code, in particular where the various params are coming from, and what `getJSON` is.

Comment: I know it is, but I need a fix for it - it's related to encoding but I don't know much about it at all - hence the question. It's making my head explode atm.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I edited the question to include the function in question.

Comment: But not how you're getting those params (urllobase, username etc).

Comment: @DanielRoseman, updated. Username comes from the url you put after /euw/